# How to install JRE using AutoIt

Tags: java, autoit

I'm trying to configure JRE installation using AutoIt:

```
If $iJava64 = 1 Then
    $hDownloadJava64 = InetGet("https://www.dropbox.com/s/s68heiccdoxhtii/Java%20Jre%20x64.exe?dl=1", @TempDir & "\Java Jre x64.exe", $INET_FORCERELOAD)
    RunWait(@TempDir & "\Java Jre x64.exe -install")
    $sMessage_stt = $sMessage_stt & "Java Jre x64 -> Done" & @CRLF
    ControlSetText("Processing status", "", "Static1", $sMessage_stt)
EndIf
```

But that doesn't work. I also tried `/S`, `/q`, but it's not working!

Comment: `Not working` - means what exactly?

Comment: I guess OP is refering to the "RunWait" command, because OP listed /S or /q which are most likely install parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work if you do it over the command line? If yes you could use following code:

```
RunWait(@ComSpec & ' /c "' & @TempDir & '\Java Jre x64.exe" -install')
```

Remeber to use ' if you need to use " for the path, because yours has spaces.

EDIT: Correct parameter:

```
RunWait(@ComSpec & ' /c "' & @TempDir & '\Java Jre x64.exe" /s')
```

Comment: i tried your command but it shows error:-http://image.prntscr.com/image/6c8041a45c5f4cedbd263a1e24521524.png

Comment: Then you need to give it the correct install parameter. You could use /? and maybe you will find it there.

Comment: After 2min research I found out /s should be the correct parameter. https://www.java.com/en/download/help/silent_install.xml

Comment: Still getting error http://image.prntscr.com/image/53b4640a10f8430fbeb667f2cc06f49b.png

Comment: Why did you write it in capital letters? Those parameters are mostly case sensitive. Use /s

Comment: WinWaitActive
ControlClick random installation is also nt working for that!

Comment: Correct Parameter: RunWait(@TempDir & "\Java Jre x64.exe /s")